# How enable exec in php 5.4?

Tags: exec

I tried to run exec, shell_exec doesn't work in php5.4. I did not find "Safe_mode" in php.ini (also read that this removed). Any solution?, Help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Prove all, and finally the solution for me is(uniformPortalServer):
```

pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}
```